# Can I manually set multiple proxies in environment?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, proxy

Consider a following PAC file:

```js
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (dnsDomainIs(host, "intranet.domain.com"))
        return "DIRECT";

    if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "10.10.5.0", "255.255.255.0"))
        return "PROXY 1.2.3.4:8080";

    return "PROXY 4.5.6.7:8080; PROXY 7.8.9.10:8080";
}
```

Is there a way to transfer those settings to `$http_proxy` and `$no_proxy` environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`no_proxy` could be set to something like `no_proxy="intranet.domain.com,*.local,..."` but otherwise environment variables are per-process strings so there's no way[†] to a) express the logic of whatever `isInNet` does or b) update the environment of existing processes that have some old and now invalid string set. Unless you kill all your processes, set a new `http_proxy` based on whatever `isInNet` does, then restart all your processes so when they `fork` they receive a new copy of the new `http_proxy` from the parent process.

If all of the processes are under your control you could write an API for adjusting environment variables. This will fail if you ever `fork` something not under your control (because then that process may have some soon wrong string set in it) and is probably needlessly complicated compared to just using the existing business logic.

[†] well there is `gdb` or otherwise monkey patching memory so no easy or not insane way

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. This resolves a long lasting dispute about trying to implement such support in our app. BTW isInNet() in the above example checks if the given IP address is part of the network, e.g. "if connected via VPN", etc.